# Как разделить число в цифры в java

Tags: java, текст

Сам вопрос: к примеру если ввести число 1276
То должно вывести число 1, 2, 7, 6. , и вводное число должно быть любых размеров.Как это сделать?

Answer (score 6):

Один из вариантов:

- Привести число к строке: `String.valueOf(<...>)`
- Строку разбить посимвольно в массив: `.split("")`
- Объединить массив в строку с нужным разделителем (`", "`): `String.join(", ", <...>)`

Код:

```
int a = 1276;
String text = String.join(", ", String.valueOf(a).split(""));
System.out.println(text);  // "1, 2, 7, 6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов:

```
Arrays.stream(String.valueOf(1276).split("")).reduce((x,y) -> x+','+y).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Без стримов выглядит так:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   long a = 124566;
   while (a > 0) {
      long l = a % 10;
      System.out.println(l);
      a /= 10;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не проходит под условие "вводное число должно быть любых размеров"

Comment: @AndrewBystrov тип long

Comment: @AndrewBystrov либо можно сразу вводить строку и делать split("")

Comment: без разницы, long или int, число может быть любых размеров, даже 100 знаков может быть. По поводу строки - да, можно делать, но тогда такой вариант уже предложили

Comment: @AndrewBystrov поэтому я и такой предложил. возможно он понадобится автору. даже для общего развития:)

Comment: @Санаев что, если длина числа, больше чем количество char в строке?

Comment: @michael_best остальная часть числа будет на следующей строке .

Answer (score -1):

**Через цикл**

```
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>;
for(int i = 0; i < str.lenght; i++){ list.add(str.charAt(i));}
```